# Method "lock" the entire screen when a socket server is started

Tags: android

Below is the receive method that implements a socket server and works perfectly.

```
    private void Receive(){ 
    log.info("Server started - waiting for the clients.");
     try {
         Boolean end = false;
         ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
         while(!end){
                 //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                 Socket s = ss.accept();
                 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                 PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
                 String st = input.readLine();

                JSONObject jsonObj;
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(st);
                    long id = jsonObj.optLong("DeviceID", count.addAndGet(1) );
                    String name = jsonObj.toString();
                    table.put(id, name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 etResult.setText(st);
                 Log.d("Tcp Example", "From client: "+st);
                 output.println("Response from Sever: Connectivity ok");
                 s.close();
                 if (st != null ){ end = true; }
         }
    ss.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

The only problem is, when I hit the button to call that method, the socket starts listening and waits for a client messages. While it does not happen, the app remains freezes and I try to hit any other button, the app may crashes.

Does anyone have a hint about how could handle it and leave the socket listening in "background" withou locking the entire screen?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a thread or AsyncTask and do all the socket functions on that.  IF it's something you're going to rarely do and want to fire it off and process the results, use an AsyncTask.  If it's something you're going to want to do constantly and don't want to run multiple workers at the same time or have multiple workers queued up, use a Thread.